# Verify if Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package is Installed without searching in windows registry?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Is there a way to know if Visual C++ 2008 and 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package is installed in the machine using C#.

Many thanks,
Chris

Comment: Reasons why you can't use the registry?

Comment: Use statically linked C runtime and will not need the redistributable package. There is option in VC project settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can look in the registry.
(registry keys to look at)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/05/10008146.aspx

Comment: If you change your answer to the linked website alternative I will give you the correct answer! **MsiQueryProductState**

Comment: not the registry... :-) scroll a little down to **MsiQueryProductState** [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa370363.aspx)

Comment: Yes, that was also an option :)  it all depends on how you want to implement it.  I am glad the link lead you to your solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like during the vcredist 2010 SP1 installation the key in Soreceri's post is no longer created (at least on my test PC running Windows 10 x64). I was able to find the key at:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x86]

The "Installed=1" REG_DWORD will be present if it is installed.

Hope this helps someone, I couldn't find it anywhere.